# How to get options from the options menu into title bar ActionBar Sherlock android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, titlebar, commonsware

I am trying to get my options to show up in the Title Bar.  I'm using ActionBarSherlock and I can figure out how to remove the title in the title bar, but would like to replace the text with 2 options from my options menu.

I'm using this code, [EmpubLite](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EmPubLite) as an example for my application, but I can't figure out how Mark (the commonsware guy) got the icons from his options menu in the title bar. My options show up at the bottom in the action bar and this is taking up unnecessary room on the screen.  I've been looking through examples here, but can't seem to find out exactly how to get options in the title bar.   I'm hoping Mark (or someone) can explain.

Comment: Do you want an overflow icon? Or did I get you wrong? Maybe you could provide a screenshot of what you want.

Comment: I want the action bar to be up in the title bar, the way my app is running it is at the bottom of the screen.  This is a waste of space since I only have 2 items that I would like to show in the action bar.

Comment: Like this: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/actionbar_actionview_overflow_menu.png?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would like to replace the text with 2 options from my options menu

Um, unless that happens automatically by removing the title, I suspect that's not possible.

> but I can't figure out how Mark (the commonsware guy) got the icons from his options menu in the title bar

Well, you see, that's covered in [this delightful little book](http://commonsware.com/Android)... :-)

More seriously, `android:showAsAction` controls whether items should be in the overflow area (`never`), should be in the action bar (`ifRoom`), or really really should be in the action bar (`always`). That being said, `always` is a hint, not a demand, and the OS may still put your action bar items in the overflow on smaller screen sizes.

You did not state which of the EmPubLite series you are experimenting with. Early on, the items are all set to `never`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/help"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/about">
    </item>

</menu>
```

By the end of the series, we have some that ideally go into the action bar:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notes"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/notes">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/download_update">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/settings">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/help">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/about">
    </item>

</menu>
```

> My options show up at the bottom in the action bar and this is taking up unnecessary room on the screen.

You have `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` set in your manifest somewhere, then.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually using the end product of EmPubsLite.  The splitActionBarWhenNarrow was what was causing the items to show in the bottom.